# How to do the merging of elements in the DataTable using php codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter, datatables

Here is some sort of LOGIC to be guided.

```
Column 1         Column 2
  A                 one
  A                 one

  B                 two
  B                 two
  B                 one

  C                 three
```

result would be:

```
Column 1         Column 2
  A                 one

  B                 two
                    one

  C                 three
```

Demos of answers will be greatly appreciated . Thanks!!

Comment: If your requirement is to display data by grouping, based on a column, you can use the [raw grouping plugin](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html)

Comment: yes it is , i already tried that . but then nothing changed :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **@user3555895** I am posting my comments as answer with little guideline:

To group your DataTable output there is a [raw grouping plugin](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html) plugin available. This page contain all documentation. Thou you need to follow some rules:

1. You must add the add-on plugin file after you have included the DataTable plugin.
2. You should handle your duplicate data yourself.

You can read about different type grouping option [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-grouping/wiki/GroupingTypes)

Hope this will enough to point you to right direction.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good about this, but I hope I can help. :)

```
<html>
<body>

    <?php
    //look, I am assuming here that your columns A, B and C are arrays (am I right?)

        $result1 = array_unique($A);
        $result2 = array_unique($B);
        $result3 = array_unique($C);

    ?>
    <table>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>

        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><?php echo $result1;?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><?php echo $result2;?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><?php echo $result3;?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

not so sure 'bout this but I hope you got my point ****chuckle**** :)

Comment: ya , i kinda get your point . but , I'll be merging the elements in both columns 1 and 2 . as you can see :)) so how do you think should I do that?

Comment: bayowt? bayowt means "genius". Just like @xiidea,he's a bayowt. And you also, you're a bayowt.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @xiidea.

I suggest [raw grouping plugin](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html) as an answer .